# Pass json object in Magento GraphQL

Tags: magento2, graphql, magento-graphql

I am required to pass json object in GraphQL Query. Is there any alternate way to do this currently GraphQL support Json as String.

Comment: Please share your code here. For more information.

Comment: There is no way you can pass json object in GraphQL. You will need to pass the json as a string and then parse it on the server side.